# Calling code behind functions from ajax call and display item by item

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm working with calling code behind functions from ajax call.
I just created a method Post, it returns a list.
I just want to check the values from client side. So simply out a alert message and pass response.d as a param. But it returns object, Object rather than actual values.
I want to know the exact way to get the values?

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static List<person> Post()
        {
            List<person> List = new List<person>();
            person p1 = new person();
            p1.name = "Sourav";
            p1.surname = "Kayal";
            List.Add(p1);
            person p2 = new person();
            p2.name = "Sourav";
            p2.surname = "Kayal";
            List.Add(p2);
            return List;
        }  
    }
    public class person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
    }


<script>

     $(document).ready(function () {

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "JavaScript.aspx/Post",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (response) {
                 var names = response.d;
                 alert(names);
             },
             failure: function (response) {
                 alert(response.d);
             }
         });
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: You will need to parse json object to get the values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to your jQuery to work you will need to serialize your `List<person>` in C# code as well -

instead of

`return List;`
add below code -

```
//Add the below using line on the top of the page where all using directives are present
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(List);
return json;
```

Since you are using jQuery - we can use the below code to parse the JSON object -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "JavaScript.aspx/Post",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "text",
         success: function (response) {
             var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            alert(obj.name);
            alert(obj.surname);
         },
         failure: function (response) {
             alert(response.d);
         }
     });
 });
```

With this above code change in your success function you should get the values from JSON object.

EDIT based on comment : 
The below line -

```
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(List);

Produces string value of:    
[ 
  {"name":"Sourav","surname":"Kayal"},
  {"name":"Sourav","surname":"Kayal"}, 
]
```

Example Reference for details - [CLICK HERE](http://matijabozicevic.com/blog/csharp-net-development/csharp-serialize-object-to-json-format-using-javascriptserialization)

Comment: What should be the return type for "return json"?

Comment: It should be `string`.

Comment: Getting error at "var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);" says 
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid character"
   
Using  JQuery version: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Try changing your datatype in ajax function to text = `datatype: "text",`

Comment: Then no error, but if I need bring data back from response I hope dataType should be "json"

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var names = JSON.parse(response);
                 alert(names.d);
               alert(names.name);
               alert(names.surname);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the success function try console logging (or F12 JavaScript debugging) to see the response object and it's members.  [Object, object] should be JavaScript failing trying to translate an object (code) as a string.  You'll likely find "exact values" looping like so:

```
  var surnames = [], prop, i;
  for (item in response) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('surname')) {
      surnames.push(item.surname);
    }
  }
  // Or
  for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    if(typeof response[i]['surname'] === 'string') {
      surnames[i] = response[i]['surname'];
    }
  }
```